# MSVC bug with xvalue built-in subscript expressions

Tags: c++, xvalue

According to the standard a built-in subscript expression, where one operand is an array rvalue, is a xvalue (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).
But when I wrote a simple test I found out that MSVC considers such expressions as lvalue!

The following code fragment successfully compiles with MSVC:

```
using T5ElemArray = int[5];
&T5ElemArray{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } [3] ;
T5ElemArray{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } [3] = 77;
int& i = T5ElemArray{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } [3] ;
```

Clang and g++ finds all three errors in the above code.
Does anybody know anything about  this bug?

Comment: *"According to the standard a built-in subscript expression..."* **Cppreference is not the standard.**

Comment: VC++ is not standards-compliant by default.

Comment: Looks like an MSVC bug. Standard reference for the downvoters: [[expr.sub\]p2](https://wg21.link/expr.sub#2.sentence-5). This is also [CWG1213](https://wg21.link/CWG1213), which I think Microsoft is claiming conformance with here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170 (Unsure, the "C++03/11 Core language features (Defects reports)" section is empty)

Comment: Apparently that code is supposed to be inside a function body?

Comment: Msvc compiles the code even with `/permissive-`. So seems like a msvc bug. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j3z63nfvf) Here is the [msvc bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-compiles-assignment-to-result-of-su/10621633)

Comment: You should report a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is [CWG1213](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1213.html) which [msvc hasn't implemented yet](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-compiles-assignment-to-result-of-su/10621633). MSVC compiles the invalid program even with `/permissive-` flag.

From [expr.sub#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub#2.sentence-5):

> With the built-in subscript operator, an expression-list shall be present, consisting of a single assignment-expression.
> One of the expressions shall be a glvalue of type “array of T” or a prvalue of type “pointer to T” and the other shall be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral type.
> The result is of type “T”.
> The type “T” shall be a completely-defined object type.50
> The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)), **except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise.**

(emphasis mine)

The above means that we're not allowed to assign to the expression `T5ElemArray{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } [3]` or take its address using `&`.

---

Here is the newly submitted msvc bug:

[MSVC compiles assignment to result of substripting an rvalue array](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-compiles-assignment-to-result-of-su/10621633)